# Opamp - Gain Simulations -LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

Hi I would be very happy if anyone can help me find the correct answer for opamp.

I simulated an opamp to find **Aol**, **1/beta** and **Aol * B** gains.I provided the picture of my Ltspice circuit, simulation results and colours of the gains below.
The Green line is Aol curve
The Blue line is 1/beta curve
The Red line is Aol*B curve

My questions are :

1. Why my 1/B phase plot (blue) does not follow Aol when the intersection happens?
2. Why does Aol phase plot (green)starts from 180 degree ?
3. We have zero around 1kHZ and pole around 10 kHz in Blue curve (1/beta curve) which i show it with white arrow in the image. So the phase plot should go up to 90 degree and then falls but it comes around 55-60 degree. Why this is happening?

[image]

Source : This is my own study

[image]
Source: This is my own study.

Answer (score 0):

It is the closed loop gain which rolls off as it approaches the open loop gain response not the 1/beta response. The 1/beta response is different to the closed loop gain response.

The zero adds up to 90 degrees of lead and would do if there wasn't a following pole. The following pole adds lag which cancels out the lead and prevents it getting up to 90 degrees. If the pole was moved up in frequency then the phase lead of the zero would get to a higher value before the lag of the pole starts to cancel it out.

The open loop phase response starts at -180 degrees because the open loop response is taken of the output with respect to the inverting input and so there is an inversion at DC due to the inverting input.

Comment: Hello Sir, when we want to find phase of AolB, we should always subtract the Phase of 1/beta from the phase of Aol right ? by considering the signs of the phases. Because ı may confused sometimes when the zeros in 1/beta becomes poles in AolB and poles in 1/beta becomes zero at AolB @user350400

Comment: @Mhan Yes, but that would be an unconventional approach. Normally we would just 
 determine the phase and gain of Aol * beta (actually -Aol * beta) by measuring phase and gain as we travel around the loop (the loop gain), so the phase of Aol added to the phase of beta. The poles of beta are the zeros of 1/beta and the zeros of beta are the poles of 1/beta, but looking at the phase and gain of 1/beta instead of beta is just adding unnecessary complication. It is easier to determine (measure) loop gain and phase by travelling around the loop in one direction.

Comment: Sir, I changed my 1/B plot to B plot. for example at same frequecny phase(B) =-31 and phase (Aol)= 93 that means the phase (Aol*B)= 62 as you said Aol is added to the B. If phase(Aol) = -10 so the phase of Aol*B would be -41 right ? as you said it always adds to phase of B. @user350400

Comment: @Mhan Think of travelling around the loop in one direction starting at the inverting input. First you would experience -180 degrees caused by the inverting input then the lag of Aol say -100 degrees. That brings you to -280 degrees. Then travelling on around the loop you would experience the lead or lag of the beta network which you then add to the -280 degrees which you have gone through so far. If the beta network has a lag of say -30 degrees then the total loop phase is -310 degrees if the beta network has a lead of +30 degrees then the total loop phase is -250 degrees.

Comment: @Mhan Be careful of what the phase scale actually means on those plots. It's confusing. It would be clearer if it started at -180 degrees at DC then Aol is always a further lag so the actual lag up to the output is more negative than -180 degrees. The scale on those plots starts at +180 degrees (which is the same as -180 degrees) then goes less positive which is adding lag so +150 degrees on the scale is actually -210 degrees of lag. So by the time the scale gets down to 0 degrees, that is actually -360 degrees of lag. All very confusing I know. Got to go out now I'll be back this evening.